# Understanding Terraform for_each loop iteration

Tags: terraform

I am learning terraform and trying to understand the for_each loop iteration in terraform.

I am iterating through a loop for creating RGs in Azure cloud and what I want to understand is the difference between accessing the value of an instance using . or [""].
So for example, below is my tfvar file:

```
resource_groups = {
  resource_group_1 = {
    name     = "terraform-apply-1"
    location = "eastus2"
    tags = {
      created_by = "vivek89@test.com"
    }
  },
  resource_group_2 = {
    name     = "terraform-apply-2"
    location = "eastus2"
    tags = {
      created_by = "vivek89@test.com"
    }
  },

  resource_group_3 = {
    name     = "terraform-apply-3"
    location = "eastus2"
    tags = {
      created_by = "vivek89@test.com"
      contact_dl = "vivek89@test.com"
    }
  }
}
```

and below is my terraform main.tf file:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "terraformRG" {
  for_each = var.resource_groups
  name = each.value.name
  location = each.value.location
  tags = each.value.tags
}
```

I am confused with the expression in for_each in RG creation block. Both the below codes works and create RGs:

```
name = each.value.name
name = each.value["name"]
```

I want to understand the difference between the two and which one is correct.

Comment: I also noticed that almost all your questions have answers, yet only a single one accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it reduces number of duplicates and increases chances for your questions to be actually answered.

Comment: Sure Marcin. Thanks. I will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equivalent as explained in the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/types.html#indices-and-attributes):

> Map/object attributes with names that are valid identifiers can also be accessed using the dot-separated attribute notation, like local.object.attrname. In cases where a map might contain arbitrary user-specified keys, we recommend using only the square-bracket index notation (local.map["keyname"]).

The main difference is that `dot` notation requires key attributes to be valid [identifiers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/syntax/configuration.html#identifiers). In contrast, the square-bracket notation works with any identifiers.

Comment: I think you maybe intended to say that the square-bracket notation works with any _expression_. 